# How to retrieve the original default ringtone that came with the Android device?

Tags: android, kotlin, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I'm trying to retrieve the first default ringtone that was present on an Android phone when it was initially bought. I've tried using `RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri()` and `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri()` methods, but they don't seem to provide the desired result.

Is there a specific method or approach to obtain the initial default ringtone that was bundled with the device when it was purchased?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the phone and OS version...

What is Samsung default ringtone?
The melody, known as Over the Horizon, is the default ringtone of the Samsung smartphone.18 Apr 2015

Over the Horizon: The Evolution of the Samsung Galaxy Brand Sound

samsung.com

Comment: But I want a way to find the original without knowing the os version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732193/how-i-get-the-default-ringtone-list-in-android-on-programmatically